# FATAL: SSPI authentication failed for user "postgres" while connecting to PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have installed PogtgreSQL Version 13 in my windows 10 OS Laptop and installed pgAdmin4.

I have made the below chnages in  pg_hba.conf and pg_ident.conf to achieve SSPI authentication. But getting "FATAL: SSPI authentication failed for user "postgres" while connecting to PosgreSQL" message while connecting to the DB

**pg_hba.conf**

```
host    all     all        127.0.0.1/32       sspi      map=SSPI
host    all     all        ::1/128            sspi      map=SSPI
```

**pg_ident.conf**

```
#MAPNAME        SYSTEM-USERNAME          PG-USERNAME

SSPI              admin@BEUNA-PC             admin
```

**Log file:**

```
2021-09-05 22:11:59.350 IST [11208] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2021-09-05 22:11:59.352 IST [11208] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-09-05 22:11:59.352 IST [11208] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-09-05 22:11:59.398 IST [8948] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-09-05 22:11:57 IST
2021-09-05 22:11:59.424 IST [11208] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-09-05 22:12:36.083 IST [16332] LOG:  no match in usermap "SSPI" for user "postgres" authenticated as "admin@BEUNA-PC"
2021-09-05 22:12:36.084 IST [16332] FATAL:  SSPI authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-09-05 22:12:36.084 IST [16332] DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 96: "host    all     all        ::1/128            sspi      map=SSPI"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to log in as 'admin', but trying to log in as 'postgres'.  Those are not the same thing.  They might *mean* the same thing, but the spelling is what counts.