# PostgreSQL user mapping not working between AD user and DB user

Tags: postgresql, kerberos

I'm trying to setup kerberos auth between my lab RHEL PSQL 13 and my AD with some success unless I try to configure user maps in pg_ident.conf as [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-username-maps.html).

My psql user is `user` and my AD user is `user@domain.com`. The later is used to connect by the users and the former is how users are defined in the DB. I need to strip the domain to match correctly with psql users.

The AD user has the machine SPN configured and the keytab has been set in psql configuration.

`pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               gss include_realm=1 krb_realm=DOMAIN.COM map=ad
```

`pg_ident.conf` file:

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
ad              /^(.*)@DOMAIN\.COM$     \1
ad              /^(.*)@domain\.com$     \1
```

Now when I try to connect using kerberos auth with `user@domain.com`, in pgAdmin4 for example, it fails with the following in the psql logs:

```
LOG:  no match in usermap "ad" for user "user@domain.com" authenticated as "user@DOMAIN.COM"
FATAL:  GSSAPI authentication failed for user "user@domain.com"
DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 99: "host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               gss include_realm=1 krb_realm=DOMAIN.COM map=ad"
```

If I set configure the `pg_hba.conf` as below instead and connect using `user` without the domain, I can connect just fine.

`pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               gss include_realm=0 krb_realm=DOMAIN.COM
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why aren't users mapping? I'm on RHEL8 running PSQL 13.

Comment: What did you put in pgAdmin4 usernme field?  "user@domain.com"?  If so, don't do that.  If you want to log in as "user", put "user".

Comment: seems that would match sAMAccountName passed on by ticket when using SSO (ie PSQL client on windows machine). 
Odd pgAdmin allows to set the username when it's not really necessary with kerberos! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out the setup works as intended in other clients when not specifying the username, as it takes the one in the kerberos ticket, aka the sAMAccountName. For example psql client on Windows will work without specifying a username.

If I put the sAMAccountName in the pgAdmin username field, it works. In my case the UPN does not match the sAMAccountName+REALM but in most cases they would match so using the left side of the UPN is safe to assume equals the sAMAccountName property.

However, I still don't know why the pg_ident.conf doesn't strip the domain name if I provide one...

Answer (score 1):

[This question is the same problem.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299121/fatal-sspi-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-while-connecting-to-posgre)

The third column in `pg_ident.conf` must match the username that you are logging into the database as. In your case, login to the database/PgAdmin4 as just `user`, not the fully qualified `user@domain.com`.

Comment: that is correct and pgAdmin shouldn't even ask for the username when kerberos is enabled imho.

Comment: @JulioQc  So then if I have more than one PostgreSQL accounts, I need to keep logging out of windows and back in as a different user?  Also, pgAdmin doesn't know if Kerberos will be used for any given connection until half way through establishing it.

Comment: @jjanes, changing the username wont change your ticket; you'll need to reauthenticate for the new user! you could logout/login or as most would do, 'run as' the user for a given application.

Comment: @JulioQc the ident mapping file can authorize one ticket to log in as a number of different database usernames, so that changing the ticket is not needed.

Comment: @jjanes that doesn't work; pgsql complains in the log with "LOG:  provided user name (<user1>) and authenticated user name (<user2>) do not match" and rejects the connection.

Comment: @dwhitemv I get your point but can you explain why the pg_ident.conf doesn't strip the domain name if I provide one? I mean, just so I can handle that user case when it occurs.

Comment: @JulioQc  It works fine if you configured the ident file to authorize it.  If you didn't, then of course it doesn't work.

Comment: @jjanes well, from my post you can see I think I configured it correctly. Yet it does not work. Can you pinpoint why?

Comment: I think you’re confusing _authentication_ (you are who you say you are) and _authorization_ (what database roles are you allowed to access). I recommend reviewing chapters 20 and 21 of the PostgreSQL docs to understand the difference and why it is needed.

Comment: @dwhitemv oh I did! And from it, my pg_ident should stip the domain part of the username. That is unless authorization happens **before** that is done. Haven't found confirmation on that flow however.